# Finding value based on range with specific criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel-2016

As shown in image, I have a range, specific value for each range. I find a formula as {=INDEX($B$1:$B$7,MATCH($C$1,VALUE(LEFT($A$1:$A$7,FIND("-",$A$1:$A$7)-1))))} to find value of a number within range, but there is some problem.As seen in image the formula returns "a" in D1 with C1 as search criteria. As we can see 17 should return "b". And this happens only for "b" as return value. I didn.t figure out what is error in formula. Please help so solve this.

Thanks in advance.And sorry for English

[D1 returns improper value when entered between 11-20](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KlceZ.png)

Comment: Can anyone see image? as I am unable to see myself too.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see your image, but with your sample and formula, I get correct result "b".

[image]

Please delete the content of A3, set Text in Format Cell, then enter "11-20" for a test.

You could also test in a new blank workbook.